# Ubuntu 22.04 Not waking up from Hibernate/Sleep. Asus Laptop Mesa Intel Graphics

Tags: 22.04, suspend, intel, hibernate

I'm looking for some help because I can't seem to figure out how to fix a bug I am experiencing. First of all, I have looked around AU, Reddit, and done quite a bit of online searching; it seems I'm the only person running a machine with intel graphics. Every solution I have found is for NVIDIA, and doesn't seem to help me at all.

The issue: When I step away from my computer, or close the screen (laptop), my computer goes into hibernate or sleep. It is still powered on, but will not resume without forcing it off by holding the power button down rebooting. While not the end of the world, it has caused some issues with documents I hadn't had a chance to save yet.

From My Settings About Tab, this is my system information: 
Hardware: ASUSTek Copmuter INC. Q50UAR
Memory: 12.0GiB
Processor: Intel Core i5-8520 CPU @ 1.6GHZ x 8
Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Disk Capacity: 1.0 TB

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.9
Windowing System: X11

BIOS

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
Q505UAR.301
```

I've tried disabling my PC from going to sleep while the screen is open, but that doesn't help if I close it. I've looked around in my bios settings for the security chip that so many others have talked about, but it is not there. And I had also tried updating a file in the /etc/grub directory that others has said helped. My computer just does not want to cooperate. It is a bit older, but still works fine otherwise. Eventually an upgrade is in order, but currently not a priority.

Thanks in advance to anyone with pointers. I don't need a full solution; a push in the right direction however would suffice.

**UPDATE:** While waiting for others input on this subject I continued my quest for answers. I came across a helpful tutorial showing how to install the latest mesa drivers (link after paragraph). It's only been an hour. But so far everything is now working properly. I have closed my laptop numerous times for it to turn back on when opened. I have also manually put it into suspend, then closed the lid, and when reopened find my PC to awaken as one would expect. So, by this, I am guessing it's a driver related issue.

[You can learn how to install the latest MESA drivers here](https://idroot.us/install-mesa-drivers-ubuntu-22-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Many of these issues are not actually related to the graphics card, but rather to the swap partition and the processor. Try the following:

- The swap partition should be the size of RAM multiplied by 1.5 (for example: 12GB RAM → 18GB swap partition).
- You need to set the following in grub2 boot: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_idle.max_cstate=4"`.

You can get [more info from here](https://github.com/Linux-Alex/HP-Victus-Linux-sleep-mode-hibernation).